# Emberjs + Rails seamlessly integrated?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, ember-data, ruby-on-rails-4

Emberjs is great but it require to re-write all routes and models if I change something on Rails. Is there a way to get all Emberjs's routes generated by Rails? So if I change a route on Rails, automatically, it generate all Emberjs's routes? The same thing to share model's validation and other things..

Or are there others JS framework for Rails?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know what you have tried so far, but one of the best ember-rails integration tools out there might be https://github.com/emberjs/ember-rails. It has boostrap commands like: `rails g ember:bootstrap` which does some boilerplate code generation.

Hope it helps.